# How to implement a function to change array cells avoiding non-exhaustive pattern errors in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, non-exhaustive-patterns

My goal is to write a function called walk, which switches the value of a labyrinth cell with its neighbour.
For example calling walk 0 labyrinthA should move the T one cell to the left.[Here i tried to change a value of a labyrinth cell in ghci.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjMMP.png)

```
showLabyrinth labyrinth =
   putStrLn $ unlines $ [[labyrinth j i | i <- [1..dimH]] | j <- [1..dimV]]
 where
   dimH = length . takeWhile (/='O') $ [labyrinth 1 i | i <- [1..]]
   dimV = length . takeWhile (/='O') $ [labyrinth i 1 | i <- [1..]]

labyrinthA 9 _  = 'O'
labyrinthA _ 16 = 'X'
labyrinthA _ 17 = 'O'
labyrinthA 1 _  = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 3 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 3  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 6  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 9  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 14 = 'M'
labyrinthA 3 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 4 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 2  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 3  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 6  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 5 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 9  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 13 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 15 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 6 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 3  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 4  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 7  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 7 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 6  = 'T'
labyrinthA 7 9  = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 11 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 13 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 14 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 15 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 8 6  = 'E'
labyrinthA 8 _  = 'X'
```

Now i tried to let the 'T' walk to the left with walk 0 labyrinthA

```
walk direction labyrinth | direction == 0 = let labyrinth (yKoord 'T') 
(xKoord 'T') = ' ' && let labyrinth (yKoord) ((xKoord+1)) = 'T'
                          | direction == 1 = undefined
                          | direction == 2 = undefined
                          | direction == 3 = undefined
```

Where as yKoord and xKoord are integers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhytJ.png)

Comment: The error is because your patterns don’t cover every possible case. (There might be other bugs in your code; I haven’t tested.) An exhaustive pattern is one that returns a result for any possible input. For example, what should be the value of `labrynthA 10 1`?

Comment: The labyrinth setup was already given, i don´t know too much about haskell yet. So if i limit the labyrinth it should work?

Comment: You said "*the string value of one char element*". What do you mean by the string value of a char element? And element of what?

Comment: I want the labyrinth cell of the 'T' (labyrinth 7 6) to be 'moving', meaning i want to write a function that can change labyrinth 7 6 to ' ' and labyrinth 8 6 to 'T'. T is representing a charakter 'walking' the labyrinth

Comment: Good luck with that. Your `labyrinthA` is a function. You can't modify functions at runtime (not even in imperative languages).

Comment: You probably want to represent a labyrinth as a list of lists, rather than a partial function of type `Int -> Int -> Char`. If you use a function, something as simple as `labyrinthA _ _ = error "no such position in labyrinth"` at the end of the definition would fix the non-exhaustive pattern problem.

Comment: `showLabyrinth labyrinthA` does not produce the exception you're describing. What is the exact command you run that produces that exception?

Comment: For example, i want to be able to write "*> let labyrhintA 1 1 = 'T'" to give the labyrhint cell the value 'T'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you’re getting is because the patterns don’t cover every case.  An **exhaustive** pattern is one that exhausts all the possibilities, that is, returns a result for every potential input value.

Here, what would happen if you called, for example, `labyrinthA 10 1`? Or `labyrinthA 0 0`?  If your compiler is not warning you about this bug at compile time, you might want to compile with the `-Wall` flag to turn warnings on.

If the program logic makes it impossible to call the function with any other values (in which case it should probably be a local function that can only be called from one place), there is a quick fix.  Add a line like this to the bottom of your function:

```
labyrinthA x y = error $ "Domain error: labyrinthA " ++ show x ++
                         " " ++ show y
```

This adds a catch-all clause matching any patterns that haven’t been covered already, satisfying the compiler.  If the function does get called with “impossible” values, the logic error will now crash the program with a more-informative debug message.

In your case, some other part of your program that you haven’t shown us calls your function with values outside its domain, which is giving you a runtime crash.  Unfortunately, we cannot help you without being able to see the code, but tracing what sequence of calls led to the crash would be a good first step.

In this specific instance, you probably don’t want to update the map of your labyrinth every time the player takes a step.  That’s not a very efficient or elegant operation in a functional language.  You might, instead, store the immutable map and then update the position of your player, to draw on top of it.  The (X,Y) coordinates could be another parameter or part of program-state data that you pass around.

This doesn’t answer your question about modifying a function after it’s been defined.  I think that’s an XY problem, but here’s a literal answer to that part of the question.  You cannot do this with the `String` type.  There are ways to get mutable state in Haskell, such as a mutable `Data.Vector.MVector` with the `ST` type, but that’s not your immediate problem.

Comment: "*the logic error will now crash the program with a debug message*" - That's what's already happening. The compiler already inserts such a catch-all clause, only the error message is different: It says "non-exhaustive patterns" instead of "domain error".

Comment: @melpomene Right, so the error message becomes more useful (giving the specific values that crashed the program) and occurs at runtime, not compile time. If the program logic is sound, and the function never can be called with values outside its domain, it would now run without error.

Comment: You're missing the point. It already is a runtime error.

Comment: @melpomene In GHC, with a bit of boilerplate added to make the code snippet compile at all, it is a compile-time error, not runtime. `labryinthA` is never even called. (That’s probably a bug.)

Comment: The code compiles and runs fine without adding anything: https://ideone.com/aBiVEj (no errors)

Comment: @melpomene That’s not the same code in the question. It needs at least one extra line of boilerplate.

Comment: @melpomene Clarified to explain why this will remove the compile-time warning and help with debugging the runtime error.

Comment: If you're referring to `main = ...`, that's not needed to compile the code (as in `ghc -c`). I only put it in because ideone doesn't let me pass custom compiler flags.

Comment: @melpomene Okay. I revised my answer to give a couple more constructive questions.

Comment: I needed to add a `module` declaration to get it to compile with `ghc -c`, either, but this probably isn’t relevant to the question. What matters here is that the question does not contain a MCVE that reproduces the bug. Some other part of the program is making a call to `labyrinthA` with invalid arguments.