# Is it possible to calculate the height and width of the following labyrinth without using list functions or list synthax

Tags: haskell

My goal is to write a function that calculates the width and height of a labyrinth by using following code. So far i only found approaches that include using list functions or list syntax, but i want to find a alternative solution without using list syntax. I am a Haskell beginner and very new to programming in general.

```
showLabyrinth labyrinth =
   putStrLn $ unlines $ [[labyrinth j i | i <- [1..dimH]] | j <- [1..dimV]]
 where
   dimH = length . takeWhile (/='O') $ [labyrinth 1 i | i <- [1..]]
   dimV = length . takeWhile (/='O') $ [labyrinth i 1 | i <- [1..]]

labyrinthA 9 _  = 'O'
labyrinthA _ 16 = 'X'
labyrinthA _ 17 = 'O'
labyrinthA 1 _  = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 2 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 3 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 3  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 6  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 9  = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 3 14 = 'M'
labyrinthA 3 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 4 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 2  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 3  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 6  = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 4 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 5 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 9  = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 13 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 15 = 'X'
labyrinthA 5 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 6 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 3  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 4  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 5  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 7  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 8  = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 6 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 7 1  = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 6  = 'T'
labyrinthA 7 9  = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 10 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 11 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 12 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 13 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 14 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 15 = 'X'
labyrinthA 7 _  = ' '
labyrinthA 8 6  = 'E'
labyrinthA 8 _  = 'X'

labyrinthB 7 6  = '.'
labyrinthB 6 6  = '.'
labyrinthB 5 6  = '.'
labyrinthB 5 7  = '.'
labyrinthB 4 7  = '.'
labyrinthB 4 8  = '.'
labyrinthB 4 9  = '.'
labyrinthB 4 10 = '.'
labyrinthB 4 11 = '.'
labyrinthB 5 11 = '.'
labyrinthB 6 11 = '.'
labyrinthB 6 12 = '.'
labyrinthB 6 13 = '.'
labyrinthB 6 14 = '.'
labyrinthB 5 14 = '.'
labyrinthB 4 14 = 'T'
labyrinthB x y  = labyrinthA x y

labyrinthC 3 14 = ' '
labyrinthC 4 14 = ' '
labyrinthC x y  = labyrinthB x y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the value of a function in Haskell, avoiding non-exhaustive patterns (duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784752/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-function-in-haskell-avoiding-non-exhaustive-patter)

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a recursive function:

```
type Labyrinth = Int -> Int -> Char
width :: Labyrinth -> Int
width l = width' 1
  where width' n | l 1 n == 'O' = n-1
                 | otherwise    = width' (n+1)
```

This is a relatively standard recursive technique.  The function `width` uses a helper function `width'` which takes the current column index (starting with `1` when first called by `width`).  It checks if the labyrinth function returns `'O'` at that column with a "pattern guard".  If it does, it returns the index of the column just before the `'O'`.  If it doesn't, it recursively calls itself to check the next column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any advice on practising recursive methodes? I am not very experienced with this technique of programming.

Comment: @Napkin implement `map`, `filter`, `foldl`, and `foldr`.

Comment: Implement `init`, `last`, `(++)` and `reverse`, too.  Most of the functions in [Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) can be implemented recursively.  The [Ninety-Nine Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems) include lots of recursion practice, too.